# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run a Flask script but i get the following error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__name__'`.How do i resolve this error ?

EDIT: I have added entry_views.py and entry_models.py files.I hope they offer more clarity on the question

Here is the error log
[image]

These are the files that i am using

run.py

```
import os
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix 
from application import create_app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app('default')
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**init**.py(create_app)

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api
from instance.config import configuration


def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(configuration[config])
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

    # Enable swagger editor
    app.config['SWAGGE_UI_JSNEDITOR'] = True
    # initialize api
    api = Api(app=app,
              title='My Diary',
              doc='/api/v1/documentation',
              description='A Simple Online Diary.')
    #doc = ('/api/v1/documentation')

    from application.views.entry_views import api as entries
    # Blueprints to be registered here

    api.add_namespace(entries, path='/api/v1')
    return app
```

entry_views.py

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, Namespace, fields
from flask import request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime


from application.models.entry_models import DiaryEntry

api = Namespace('entries', Description='Operations on entries')

# data structure to store entries
entries = {}

entry = api.model('entry', {
    'title': fields.String(description='location of the driver'),
    'body': fields.String(description='end-point of the journey')

})


class Entries(Resource):

    @api.doc(responses={'message': 'entry added successfully.',
                        201: 'Created', 400: 'BAD FORMAT'})
    @api.expect(entry)
    def post(self):
        """creates a new diary entry."""
        data = request.get_json()
        # Check whether there is data
        if any(data):
            # save entry to data structure


            # set id for the entry offer
            entry = DiaryEntry(data)
            entry_id = len(entries) + 1
            entries[(entry_id)] = entry.getDict()
            response = {'message': 'entry offer added successfully.',
                            'offer id': entry_id}
            return response, 201

        else:
            return {'message': 'make sure you provide all required fields.'}, 400

    @api.doc('list of entries', responses={200: 'OK'})
    def get(self):
        """Retrieves all available entries"""
        return (entries)

api.add_resource(entries, '/entries')


class Singleentry(Resource):

    @api.doc('Get a single entry',
             params={'entry_id': 'Id for a single entry offer'},
             responses={200: 'OK', 404: 'NOT FOUND'})
    def get(self, entry_id):
        """Retrieves a single entry."""
        try:
            entry = entries[int(entry_id)]
            entry['id'] = int(entry_id)
            return jsonify(entry)
        except Exception as e:
            return {'message': 'entry does not exist'}, 404


api.add_resource(Singleentry, '/entries/<string:entry_id>')
```

entry_models.py

```
from datetime import datetime


class DiaryEntry(object):
    """
    Model of a diary entry
    title: title of the diary entry,
    body: body of the diary entry

    """

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.title = data['title']
        self.body = data['body']


    def getDict(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Comment: What is that `application.views.entry_views`? it looks like you're passing it as a `flask_restplus.Namespace`, but it's actually just a `dict`.

Comment: @abarnert, i have added the file.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Should your code be like this(lowercase d)

```
api = Namespace('entries', description='Operations on entries')
```

instead of:

```
api = Namespace('entries', Description='Operations on entries')
```

looking at the [code examples](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html)  that seems to be the difference

Comment: Is it possible to try renaming the namespace to something different

Comment: should this be the Entries resource or an empty dict? 
`api.add_resource(entries, '/entries')`